# Issue with positioning the top navigation

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website - see here http://www.kaniamea.com/2/
I am trying to figure out how to position the nav blue navbar to appear like this http://www.kaniamea.com/2/header.png
On this example the navbar goes a bit out of the content area which creates a nice wrap around effect. My current code is

```
display: block;
background-image:url(images/nav-bg.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 682px;
height: 48px;
float:right;
```

How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css:

```
#nav {margin-right: -2em;}
```